# can nginx run a query to test rather it's safe to proxy a request?

Tags: nginx, proxy

I have learned that there is a bug in the system I'm using to generate my rest interface.  If I make a query to a 'domain' that does not exist the system I'm using will throw an exception that isn't handled properly, ultimatley resulting in zombie threads that will never be reclaimed.

I would like to prevent losing threads by doing a check to see if a domain is present prior to proxying a request to the domain, all from within nginx if possible.

My nginx conf is a little complicated.  For the relevant part I have a default domain that my multitude of GUI's will use, though some UI's must use a different domain and if so I add a seperate location directive for them.  My default domain directive looks something like this:

```
location ~ ^/UI/[^/]*-api/ {
   rewrite ^/UI/[^/]*-api/(.*) /<base_url>/domains/<domain name>/$1 break;
   proxy_pass https://<ip>:<port>
   proxy_cache UI-CACHE;
}
```

I already know there are some proxy options I can add to cut back on the number of requests proxy to the backend and will be adding those shortly, so feel free to presume they exist in your answer.

What I want to do is add a way to check rather a domain exists before I proxy any requests to location using that domain.  So ideally if I receive a requests for /UI/foo-api/application/  I would like to first do a query to //domains/  check if  is listed in the results, and only proxy the request if it is.  if I don't see the domain name I'd like to return an appropriate error code instead.

To be more exact the latency would be too high to do a check to veify a domain exists with every request.  Instead I'd like to cache the check to //domains/ for X seconds.  If I can somehow also make it so that a proxied requests receives an error message the next proxy to the same API would check if a domain exists, even if the last cached domain check hasn't expired, that would be useful.

In an ideal world I'd love to be able to write a directive that would work for any domain, meaning that if a user later adds a specific location for /ui/bar-api/ and /ui/baz-api/ with different domain names the logic I wrote to check domain's existance would automatically apply to checking the bar-domain or baz-domain existed for the respective calls without the need to add any additional logic to the location directive, though that's probably too much to ask for.

Is there any method within nginx which would allow me to do this?